# Can we access a variable declared using 'var' keyword inside a block?

Tags: javascript, variables, web, scope, javascript-scope

A variable is declared using 'var' keyword inside a block ( {...} ). Can we access that variable outside the block?
I searched on several websites and the answer was 'yes'. 'Yes we can access the variable' it said.
But when I executed this on a browser console it said "the variable is not defined". Any thoughts why this is so?

Here's the screenshot of the same

[image: 1]

I expected it to give 12345.

Comment: Where did you read it? You can access it using your debugger when you set a breakpoint in this block.

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting pictures of code.

Comment: This is one of those situations where maybe you were expecting _hoisting_ to occur, but hoisting does not hoist a variable outside of the scope of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A variable is declared using 'var' keyword inside a block ( {...} ). Can we access that variable outside the block? I searched on several websites and the answer was 'yes'.

tldr; It's more precise to say *Yes, unless that block is a function body*.

---

`var` scopes a variable to the nearest **function**.

The body of the function (excepting some arrow functions) is a block.

Not all blocks are associated with functions.

```js
{
    var inBlock = 1;
}

console.log(inBlock); // This logs 1

function aFunction() {
    var inFunction = 2;
}

aFunction();

console.log(inFunction); // This triggers a reference error
```

Comment: Yeah didn't quite got the meaning of 'function scope' at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variable but that doesn't necessarily mean your variable will actually have a value before passing through said block.

`var` will be known throughout the entire function. So if you declare `var x` at the end of your function (or in an if-block nested in a while in another while) and assign it there, you will be able to call it at the start of the function, but the value will be "undefined" since it hasn't been assigned a value yet at that point of the execution.

Hence why `var` needs careful consideration on usage to make sure you actually need said variable outside the block where you're using/initializing it.

for-loops are (in my opinion) easiest to explain this with:

```
for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    // do something
};
```

The variable `i` here will actually be known OUTSIDE the for-loop. It will be undefined before going through the for loop and will have the value of the last iteration after the for loop. (As oppposed to using `let` which will make it so variable `i` is not known outside the for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared with `var` has `global` and `function` scope but does not have `block scope`. Which means these variables are only accessible inside a function or globally.

```
// if we try to access it from function scope, it is not accessible
function greeting() {
  var sayHi = "Hello"
  return sayHi
}

console.log(sayHi) // sayHi is undefined. Because it has function scope



// if we try to access it from block scope, it is accessible.
if (1 < 2) {
 var sayBye = "Bye"
}

console.log(sayBye) // prints 'Bye', because it has no block scope
```

Comment: I confused it with function when it said block. Now everything's clear.

Answer (score -1):

After execution of the function, the variable will no longer be available and it will be referencing the globally scope which don't have your variable.